# JFreeChart render StackedAreaChart with splines

Tags: jfreechart, spline

I am looking for a way to render a `StackedAreaChart` with splines
I guess I am after some `StackedSplineAreaChart`
`XYSplineRenderer` is doing a nice job but does not cover areas
**Is there a trick to render AreaCharts with splines?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `StackedAreaRenderer` nor `StackedXYAreaRenderer` currently (JFreeChart 1.0.15)  do have support for splines. The feature you are requesting is currently not supported by JFreeChart.

However, for the `StackedXYAreaRenderer` it shoudn't be too hard to enhance it to support splines, based on the `XYSplineRenderer` implementation. You would need to create your own renderer class and override the `drawItem()` method.